# Google maps javascript API 3 key generation

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, dom, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to embed a google map into my website using google maps javasrcipt API 3. I have generated a key and entered it as follow:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzSyBZsRvsDrBFh4-kVadHK&sensor=true">
</script>
```

(Look at the parameter key= in the previous line of code).

When I open my application , I get a notice that the key I entered is not valide and the map crashes.

Can anyone help me on that !

Comment: Sounds like you've not generated the key correctly!  You can remove the key parameter and the map should work

Comment: The key is generated automatically by google themselves, so the key by itself is supposedly valid. I am just wondering whether there is something in the configuration that I must change maybe ?

Comment: Have you authorized that key for the google maps api v3? Is it a browser key? Are the allowed referers correct (or if it is a server key are the allowed IPs correct)?

Comment: Yes, I did authorize the key on my console and it is a browser key not a server key. I must have done something wrong in some configuration :/ and I just can't spot it.

Answer (score 0):

The browser key is used when you load other APIs through the javascript.

You can keep your include simplified with the [Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) and [Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js)

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=true"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init"></script>
```

and inside your code, say Fusion Tables, you can add it this way:

```
function init() {
    gapi.client.load('fusiontables', 'v1', function() {
        gapi.client.setApiKey( "YOUR_BROWSER_API_KEY_HERE" );
        //Other stuff to do on loading this
        gapi.client.fusiontables.query.sql({sql:["SELECT * FROM", TABLE_NAME].join(' '), fields:'rows, columns'}).execute( function(json) {
            //Do what you need to parse the json response
            //Set up KML Layers
            //etc... make sure to check if maps is loaded too
            json.rows.forEach( function(t) {
                console.log( t );
            });
        });
    });
}
```

And you will be able to do authorized (not OAuth 2.0) stuff in that manner.