# Unable to use my API key using an embedded traffic map in custom receiver and google drive webhosting

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-drive-api, chromecast

I'm trying to build a custom receiver for chromecast that contains a traffic map layer using google maps. When I use the example embedded map, it displays correctly. But when I try to using my API key, I get this error:

> Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. This
>   site is not authorized to use the Google Maps client ID provided. If
>   you are the owner of this application, you can learn more about
>   registering URLs in the Getting Started chapter of the Maps API for
>   Business documentation.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PGfgv/682/) of how I expect it to behave. When I change the script to be

`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=MYKEY"></script>`

I get my error. Under the google maps api it talks about [whitelisting the site](https://developers.google.com/console/help/#restrictingusage) so it can use the API key. Where I think there may be an issue is with my host. I'm using google drive web hosting to host the custom receiver (which hasn't given me any issues except this).

I've tried whitelisting

```
https://googledrive.com/host/HostingID/receiver.html
https://googledrive.com/host/*
https://googledrive.com/*
```

But nothing seems to help. What am I missing here?

Comment: What happens if you drop "https://" prefix when whitelisting?

Comment: and what if you just host it, for testing, on a traditional web server?

Comment: @AliNaddaf unfortunately I don't have access to a server with certs for ssl hosting. on my regular webserver it still doesn't work

Comment: After referencing [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22353463/google-maps-javascript-api-3-key-generation?rq=1) I'm pretty sure I only use my key when using simplified maps.

Comment: As far as Cast is concerned, you do not need to have https as long as your app is not published, so any web server would do.